# Adding breaks in new csv

Tags: php, csv

I am trying to adding new line within cell but it show in \n in csv . I don't know whats wrong with foreach loop but  i statically write in csv it generated well in csv for ex: 
**fputcsv($fh, array('D', "E\nF\nG", 'H'), "\t");**

```
$classreport = array(
    array(
        'name' => 'Vick',
        'std' => 'A',
        'marks' => array(10, 20, 30, 40)
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'Josh',
        'std' => 'B',
        'marks' => array(20, 40)
    ),
);


$fh = fopen('test3.csv', 'w+');
fwrite($fh, "sep=\t" . "\r\n");
$colums=array('name','std','mark');
fputcsv($fh, $colums, "\t");
foreach($classreport as $student) {

   $tt=implode(',',$student['marks']);
  fputcsv($fh, array($student['name'], $student['std'],trim(str_replace(',','\n',$tt)) ), "\t");

} 
fclose($fh);
```

[image]

Comment: What does the csv look like (as in, in notepad)

Comment: same name std mark
Vick A "10\n20\n30\n40"
Josh B "20\n40"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because a [single quote](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) doesn't substitute "\n" to a newline. You need to double-quote that like this:

```
foreach($classreport as $student) {
  $tt=implode(',',$student['marks']);
  fputcsv($fh, array($student['name'],$student['std'],trim(str_replace(',',"\n",$tt)) ), "\t");
}
```